# Extracting one-dimension array from a multidimension array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, extract

How can I write a function to extract a single dimension array from a multidimension one in VBA?

Suppose I have:

- a 3-dimension array `a(3,3,3)`,

then now I want to extract:

- `a(1,1,1)`,
- `a(1,2,1)`

and `a(1,3,1)` into a new array.

I use here 3-or-more dimension array. It's because I already know we can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Index` to do extraction from a 2-dimension array.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried writing a loop-based function to do this?  It's pretty straightforward (assuming you do not need to handle arbitrarily-dimensioned arrays).

Comment: Chip Pearson's web site has a lot of good stuff on arrays in excel vba ... [here](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/VBAArrays.htm)

Comment: Thank you @OldUgly, the site is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

While the worksheet's [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) can slice out a 'row' or 'column' of a 2D array, I don't know of any way to use it to peel off a slice of a 3D array. It would seem that you need to assign the values 'manually'.

```
Sub peel_out_arr()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim a() As Variant, b As Variant

    ReDim a(1 To 3, 1 To 3, 1 To 3)

    For i = LBound(a, 1) To UBound(a, 1)
        For j = LBound(a, 2) To UBound(a, 2)
            For k = LBound(a, 3) To UBound(a, 3)
                a(i, j, k) = i + j + k
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i

    b = Array(a(1, 1, 1), a(1, 2, 1), a(1, 3, 1))

    For i = LBound(b) To UBound(b)
        Debug.Print b(i)         '<~~ results are 3, 4, 5
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help. I decided to write a sub using loops to get the second dimension of the array.

```
Sub slicearray(vArr As Variant, result As Variant, i As Long, j As Long)
    Dim k As Long
    ReDim result(LBound(vArr, 2) To UBound(vArr, 2))
    For k = LBound(vArr, 2) To UBound(vArr, 2)
        result(k) = vArr(i, k, j)
    Next k
End Sub
```

By this sub, if I declare a variable `b` as a dynamic array of type `Variant`, I can get the result by

```
Call slicearray(a,b,1,1)
```